# Erro Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) Busca em Árvore Binária

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um trabalho que realiza uma busca de uma chave (um valor int) em uma árvore binária populada a partir de um arquivo *txt*. O arquivo *txt* possui em cada linha o seguinte registro: uma chave (int), um dado1 (long int) e um dado2 (char[1000]). Por exemplo, a primeira linha poderia ser: 
*"5 13734842 casa de papel"*.

Fiz um programa simples para gerar aleatóriamente os dados no arquivo txt, formatado e com o número de linhas desejado. Na função `main` populei minha árvore realizando a leitura do arquivo *txt* criado e inserindo cada registro na árvore criada com a função `insere_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz, Registro valor)`. Então chamando a função `consulta_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz, int valor)` passo um valor inteiro para realizar a busca na árvore. Essa função retorna *0* quando o elemento não é encontrado e *1* quando é encontrado na árvore.

O programa funciona normalmente para um registro pequeno no arquivo *txt* (com 5 linhas, por exemplo, e com poucos caracteres funcionou normalmente), o problema acontece quando gero um registro grande, com o arquivo *txt* contendo várias linhas e muitos caracteres, acusando então o erro com a mensagem ***Segmentation fault; dump do core***

Acredito que o erro esteja relacionada com alguma alocação de memória mal feita, tentei utilizar uma função `libera_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz)` que libera memória da árvore no fim do programa mas nada mudou. Não sei onde esse erro poderia está e como modificaria alguma rotina para solucionar esse problema, visto que ele funciona normalmente para registros pequenos. Esse é o código com as funções que utilizei para criação, inserção e consulta na árvore de busca:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ArvoreBinaria.h"

#define TAM_REG 100000

using namespace std;

struct registro{
    int chave;
    int dado1;
    char dado2[1000];
};

struct NO{
    Registro info;
    struct NO *esq;
    struct NO *dir;
};

ArvBin* cria_ArvBin(){
    ArvBin* raiz =  (ArvBin*) malloc(sizeof(ArvBin));
    if(raiz != NULL){
        *raiz = NULL;
    }
    return raiz;
}

void libera_NO(struct NO* no){
    if(no == NULL)
        return;
    libera_NO(no->esq);
    libera_NO(no->dir);
    free(no);
    no = NULL;    
}

void libera_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz){
    if(raiz == NULL)
        return;
    libera_NO(*raiz);//libera cada nó
    free(raiz);//libera a raiz

}

int insere_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz, Registro valor){
    if(raiz==NULL)
        return 0;
    struct NO* novo;
    novo = (struct NO*) malloc(sizeof(struct NO));
    if(novo == NULL)//se deu erro na alocação
        return 0;
    novo->info = valor;
    novo->dir = NULL;
    novo->esq = NULL;
    //procura onde inserir!
    if(*raiz==NULL)//se minha arvore é uma arvore vazia. se for só inserir
        *raiz = novo;
    else{
        struct NO* atual = *raiz;
        struct NO* ant = NULL;
        //navega nos nós da arvore até chegar em um nó folha
        while(atual!=NULL){
            ant = atual;
            if(valor.chave == atual->info.chave){
                free(novo);
                return 0;//elemento já existe
            }
            if(valor.chave > atual->info.chave)
                atual = atual->dir;
            else
                atual = atual->esq;
        }
        //insere como filho desse nó folha
        if(valor.chave > ant->info.chave)
            ant->dir= novo;
        else
            ant->esq=novo;     
    }
    return 1;
}

//busca
int consulta_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz, int valor){
    if(raiz==NULL)
        return 0;
    struct NO* atual = *raiz;
    while(atual != NULL){
        if(valor == atual->info.chave){
            return 1;
        }
        if(valor > atual->info.chave)
            atual = atual->dir;
        else
            atual = atual->esq;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ArvBin* raiz = cria_ArvBin();
    int i = 0;
    Registro valor[TAM_REG];    

    //carrega arquivo, lê dados e insere na árvore criada 
    FILE* arq = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");
    if(arq!=NULL){
        while(fscanf(arq, "%d %d %[^\n]s", &valor[i].chave, 
                     &valor[i].dado1, valor[i].dado2) != EOF) {
            insere_ArvBin(raiz, valor[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    int busca = consulta_ArvBin(raiz, 5);
    if(busca == 0)
        printf("Não encontrado!\n");
    else
        printf("Encontrado!\n");   

    return 0;
}
```

O *.h* com todas as funções da TAD:

```
#ifndef ARVOREBINARIA_H
#define ARVOREBINARIA_H

typedef struct registro Registro;
typedef struct NO* ArvBin;
ArvBin* cria_ArvBin();
void libera_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz);
int estaVazia_ArvBin(ArvBin *razi);
int altura_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz);
int totalNO_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz);
void preOrdem_ArvBin(ArvBin* raiz);
void emOrdem_ArvBin(ArvBin* raiz);
void posOrdem_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz);
int insere_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz, Registro valor);
int remove_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz, int valor);
int consulta_ArvBin(ArvBin *raiz, int valor);

#endif /* ARVOREBINARIA_H */
```

Percebi realizando testes que em registros de até 8000 o programa funciona normalmente, a partir de 9000 já acontece o erro ***Segmentation fault; dump do core***.

O código para gerar os arquivos *txt* aleatórios para teste:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TAM_TXT 100000
#define MAX_STR_SIZE    50
#define MIN_STR_SIZE    5

using namespace std;

char* geraStringAleatoria(){

    char *validchars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char *novastr;
    register int i;
    int str_len;

    // inicia o contador aleatório
    //srand ( time(NULL ));

    // novo tamanho
    str_len = (rand() % MAX_STR_SIZE );

    // checa tamanho
    str_len += ( str_len < MIN_STR_SIZE ) ? MIN_STR_SIZE : 0;

    // aloca memoria
    novastr = ( char * ) malloc ( (str_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if ( !novastr ){
        printf("[*] Erro ao alocar memoria.\n" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // gera string aleatória
    for ( i = 0; i < str_len; i++ ) {
        novastr[i] = validchars[ rand() % strlen(validchars) ];
        novastr[i + 1] = 0x0;
    }

        return novastr;

}

int escreverArquivo(){
  //srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );

  int chave = rand() % INT_MAX;
  long int dado1 = rand() % LONG_MAX;

  FILE* info = fopen("arquivo[100000L].txt", "w");

  int i=0;
  while(i<TAM_TXT){
    fprintf(info,"%d %ld %s\n", (rand() % INT_MAX), (rand() % LONG_MAX), geraStringAleatoria());
    ++i;
  } 
}

int main() {

    escreverArquivo();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nao é porque so cabem 3 registros no seu vetor? Poucas linhas com muitos caracteres funciona? E muitas linhas com poucos caracteres?

Comment: Consegue colocar num pastebin o arquivo que lhe crasha para que seja fácil de testar? Numa nota adicional o seu código é basicamente código C com `cout`, no qual deveria então usar apenas C e `printf` por questões de consistência. Caso contrário deveria considerar utilizar tudo de C++, como por exemplo `new` e `delete` em vez de `malloc` e `free`, entre outras coisas.

Comment: @BrunoPastre Me esqueci de mudar o valor do tamanho do vetor de registros que é de acordo com o tamanho do arquivot txt gerado. Fiz a correção do código na pergunta.  O problema continua para registros acima de 8000.

Comment: @Isac Não consigo colocar no pastebin o arquivo com muitos registros, editei a pergunta e coloquei o código para geração dos arquivos txt para os testes. Obg pela dica :)

Answer (score 1):

Repare que a sua função `libera_NO()` parece tentar comparar se o nó passado aponta para nulo de uma forma estranha, repare bem:

```
if(no = NULL)
    return;

libera_NO(no->esq)
```

Isso não se trata de uma comparação! Isso vai fazer com que o nó pasado, mesmo que válido, comece a apontar para nulo! Logo em seguida, a expressão boleana seria interpretada como `if(0)`, fazendo o fluxo não passar pelo `return`.

Na tentativa de acessar o ponteiro nulo `no->esq` na próxima linha, o seu programa vai ser terminado pelo sistema operacional com um erro de segmentação.

Comment: Realmente estava errado, me esqueci do ==.. Fiz alteração, mas o problema persiste para arquivos grandes (100000 registros por exemplo).. Editei a pergunta com a alteração e coloquei o código para gerar os arquivos _txt_, se for possível realize os testes por favor para ver se o erro persiste, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O seu header `ArvoreBinaria.h`, possui uma definição de tipo:

```
typedef struct NO* ArvBin;
```

Isso significa que `ArvBin` se trata de um `ponteiro para um nó`, seu código faz uma tremenda confusão com isso, por exemplo:

```
ArvBin* cria_ArvBin(){
    ArvBin* raiz =  (ArvBin*) malloc(sizeof(ArvBin));
    if(raiz != NULL){
        *raiz = NULL;
    }
    return raiz;
}
```

Quando você faz algo do tipo `ArvBin * raiz;` você está declarando um `ponteiro para um ponteiro de um nó`, ou seja, um `struct NO**`!

Seu código repete o mesmo erro múltiplas vezes, e se está funcionando, mesmo com pouco registros, trata-se de um milagre!

Seu código poderia ser simplesmente assim:

```
typedef struct NO ArvBin;

...

ArvBin* cria_ArvBin(){
    ArvBin* raiz =  (ArvBin*) malloc(sizeof(ArvBin));
    return raiz;
}
```

Ou até mesmo:

```
typedef struct NO ArvBin;

...

ArvBin* cria_ArvBin(){
    return (ArvBin*) malloc(sizeof(ArvBin));
}
```

Comment: No caso de uma árvore binária de busca, realmente não é necessário um ponteiro para ponteiro, mas para a AVL, que terei q testar tbm, vai ser necessário para os balanceamentos, assim irei aproveitar o código para utilizar em outras TADs. Não consegui compreender esse problema de se usar o ponteiro para ponteiro, a única diferença que vou ter um nó especial raiz apontando para o primeiro nó da árvore, assim poderei manipular a raiz mais facilmente na árvore AVL. Aki o erro persiste c a alteração, se você tiver um tempo e for possível você testa-lo ia ser ótimo :) Valeuu!

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo seu raciocínio, segue uma solução em `C` (testada) capaz de resolver o seu problema, com uma abstração mais granulada das entidades: `árvore binária`, do `nó` e do `registro`. Repare que se trata de uma solução *verdadeiramente* dinâmica, ou seja, aceita arquivos com qualquer quantidade de registros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* ************************************************************************** */
/* *                           TIPOS E ESTRUTURAS                           * */
/* ************************************************************************** */

/* Tipos */
typedef struct no_s no_t;
typedef struct arvore_binaria_s arvore_binaria_t;
typedef struct registro_s registro_t;


/* Representa um registro */
struct registro_s
{
    int chave;
    int dado1;
    char dado2[1000];
};

/* Representa um noh */
struct no_s
{
    registro_t reg;        /* Registro */
    no_t * esq;            /* Ponteiro para o noh da esquerda */
    no_t * dir;            /* Ponteiro para o noh da direita */
};

/* Representa uma arvore binaria */
struct arvore_binaria_s
{
    no_t * raiz;    /* Ponteiro para o noh raiz */
    int qtd;        /* Quantidade de nos contidos na arvore */
};


/* ************************************************************************** */
/* *                          PROTOTIPOS DAS FUNCOES                        * */
/* ************************************************************************** */

/* Cria uma arvore binaria vazia em memoria */
arvore_binaria_t * arvore_criar( void );

/* Libera memoria ocupada por uma arvore binaria */
void arvore_liberar( arvore_binaria_t * arv );

/* Cria um nó em memoria */
no_t * no_criar( registro_t * reg );

/* Libera memoria ocupara por um nó */
void no_liberar( no_t * no );

/* Insere registro na Arvore de acordo com a "chave" do registro */
int arvore_inserir_registro( arvore_binaria_t * arv, registro_t * registro );

/* Pesquisa um registro na arvore usando a "chave" como argumento */
registro_t * arvore_buscar_registro( arvore_binaria_t * arv, int chave );

/* Cria uma arvore binaria em memória a partir de um arquivo TXT */
arvore_binaria_t * arvore_criar_do_arquivo( const char * arq );

/* ************************************************************************** */
/* *                              IMPLEMENTACAO                             * */
/* ************************************************************************** */

arvore_binaria_t * arvore_criar( void )
{
    arvore_binaria_t * arv = (arvore_binaria_t*) malloc(sizeof(arvore_binaria_t));

    arv->raiz = NULL;
    arv->qtd = 0;
    return arv;
}


void arvore_liberar( arvore_binaria_t * arv )
{
    if(arv == NULL)
        return;

    no_liberar(arv->raiz);
    free(arv);
}


no_t * no_criar( registro_t * reg )
{
    no_t * no = (no_t*) malloc(sizeof(no_t));

    no->esq = NULL;
    no->dir = NULL;

    no->reg.chave = reg->chave;
    no->reg.dado1 = reg->dado1;
    strcpy( no->reg.dado2, reg->dado2 );

    return no;
}


void no_liberar( no_t * no )
{
    if(no == NULL)
        return;

    no_liberar(no->esq);
    no_liberar(no->dir);
    free(no);
}


int arvore_inserir_registro( arvore_binaria_t * arv, registro_t * registro )
{
    if( arv == NULL )
        return -1;

    if( arv->raiz == NULL )
    {
        no_t * novo = no_criar( registro );

        arv->raiz = novo;
        arv->qtd = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        no_t * atual = arv->raiz;
        no_t * ant = NULL;

        while( atual != NULL )
        {
            ant = atual;

            if( registro->chave == atual->reg.chave )
                return -1; /* Registro jah esxistente! */

            if( registro->chave > atual->reg.chave )
                atual = atual->dir;
            else
                atual = atual->esq;
        }

        no_t * novo = no_criar( registro );

        if( registro->chave > ant->reg.chave )
            ant->dir = novo;
        else
            ant->esq = novo;

        /* Incrementa contador de nós na arvore binária */
        arv->qtd++;
    }

    /* Em caso de sucesso, retorna quantidade de nós na arvore */
    return arv->qtd;
}


registro_t * arvore_buscar_registro( arvore_binaria_t * arv, int chave )
{
    if( arv == NULL )
        return NULL;

    no_t * atual = arv->raiz;

    while( atual != NULL )
    {
        if( chave == atual->reg.chave )
            return &atual->reg;

        if( chave > atual->reg.chave )
            atual = atual->dir;
        else
            atual = atual->esq;
    }

    return NULL;
}


arvore_binaria_t * arvore_criar_do_arquivo( const char * arq )
{
    arvore_binaria_t * arv = NULL;
    registro_t aux;

    FILE * fp = fopen( arq, "r");

    if(!arq)
        return NULL;

    arv = arvore_criar();

    while( fscanf( fp, "%d %d %[^\n]s", &aux.chave, &aux.dado1, aux.dado2 ) != EOF )
    {
        /* Insere registro na arvore */
        int n = arvore_inserir_registro( arv, &aux );

        /* Exibe mensagem de avido em caso de erro de insercao em um dos registros */
        if( n < 0 )
            fprintf( stderr, "Erro Inserindo Registro: chave=%d, dado1=%d, dado2='%s'\n", aux.chave, aux.dado1, aux.dado2 );
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return arv;
}

/* ************************************************************************** */
/* *                                    MAIN()                              * */
/* ************************************************************************** */

int main( void )
{
    /* Cria arvore binaria a partir do arquivo especificado */
    arvore_binaria_t * arv = arvore_criar_do_arquivo( "arquivo[100000L].txt" );

    if(!arv)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Erro Carregado Arvore Binaria a partir do Arquivo.");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Pesquisa registro com a chave especificada (no caso: 1773986255) */
    registro_t * registro = arvore_buscar_registro( arv, 1773986255 );

    if( registro == NULL )
    {
        printf("Registro nao encontrado!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Registro Encontrado: chave=%d, dado1=%d, dado2='%s'\n", registro->chave, registro->dado1, registro->dado2 );
    }

    arvore_liberar( arv );

    return 0;
}

/* eof */
```

Testando com um arquivo de `100.000` registros usando o [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/):

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck --show-reachable=yes ./arvore_binaria 
==4657== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4657== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4657== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4657== Command: ./arvore_binaria
==4657== 
Erro Inserindo Registro: chave=972927972, dado1=1173501325, dado2='DswGY'
Erro Inserindo Registro: chave=1942444306, dado1=291188190, dado2='QNQBgfoNflfwYwmXwgwZPAg'
Registro Encontrado: chave=1773986255, dado1=1078115008, dado2='tkxXNlSxbKnJpvXfCfaLSESAweeHdrdwBB'
==4657== 
==4657== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4657==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4657==   total heap usage: 100,000 allocs, 100,000 frees, 102,398,536 bytes allocated
==4657== 
==4657== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4657== 
==4657== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4657== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Show! valeu man!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui encontrar uma solução! Quando aloca dinamicamente minha struct Registro ele funciona normalmente para registros grandes. Testei até 1.000.000 de registros e a busca funcionou normalmente, claro que um pouco mais lenta na medida que aumento o número de registros:

```
#define TAM_REG 1000000

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Registro *valor = (Registro *)malloc(TAM_REG * sizeof(Registro));

    ArvBin* raiz = cria_ArvBin();
    int i = 0;   
    FILE* arq = fopen("arquivo[1000000L].txt", "r");
    if(arq!=NULL){
        while(fscanf(arq, "%d %d %[^\n]s", &valor[i].chave, &valor[i].dado1, valor[i].dado2) != EOF) {
            insere_ArvBin(raiz, valor[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    int busca = consulta_ArvBin(raiz, 1398063906);
    if(busca == 0)
        printf("Não encontrado!\n");
    else
        printf("Encontrado!\n");   

    libera_ArvBin(raiz);

    return 0;
}
```

Como suspeitava o erro está ligado a alocação na memória na medida que o vetor de Resgitro ficava grande. Só não consigo entender o porquê disso. Meu pc possui 8gb de ram e acho que não era pra haver problemas em alocar a memória em tempo de compilação (como estava fazendo antes, alterando o tamanho do vetor de Registro com a variável TAM_REG) ou em tempo de execução, dinamicamente como fiz agora. Se alguém pudesse ter um explicação teórica para a questão acho que seria legal! Vlw!

Comment: Nessa solução, mesmo usando alocação dinamica de memória com a chamada de `malloc()`, ainda assim, sua a memória de trabalho ainda é estática, pois você aloca **sempre** a mesma quatidade de memória. Se o arquivo de entrada possuir mais do que `100.000` registros, os restantes ficarão de fora, e se o seu arquivo possui menos do que `100.000` registros, você usou memória denecessáriamente.